# What is the best way to call multiple functions from an onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I have an object that contained a bunch of functions. I'd like to be able to get a bunch of these functions to fire on click of just one function. I've got it working but I don't think I have the best solution. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<button onclick="_this.call(_this.func1(), _this.func2())">click me</button>
```

JS:

```
var _this = {};

_this.func1 = function() {
  console.log('func1');
};

_this.func2 = function() {
  console.log('func2');
};

_this.call = function() {};
```

**edit**

My main objective is to only fire certain functions at a time so I will probably have to look at using the arguments variable in the function to fire the functions.

Comment: Create a function that call all the functions.... use a MVW,MVVM framework like Angular, Backbone.

Comment: Why are you specifying click handlers in the HTML in the first place?  I'd suggest you read about the advantages of unobtrusive Javascript and use event listeners.

Comment: I'm using a custom front end framework that includes ractive.js which uses on-click="". I've just changed my question so it would make sense without ractive.js.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is to keep html with the least JS (or better no JS at all).

So here it would be

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="_this.handleOnClick())">click me</button>
```

In JS:

```
var _this = {};

_this.handleOnClick = function() {
    _this.func1();
    _this.func2();
}

_this.func1 = function() {
  console.log('func1');
};

_this.func2 = function() {
  console.log('func2');
};

_this.call = function() {};
```

**And better**

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    _this.handleOnClick()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one.

```
function one() {};
function two() {};
function three() {};

var button.document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
   one();
   two();
   three();
, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call all object methods this way:

```
var obj = {
    func1: function() { console.log('func1'); },
    func2: function() { console.log('func2'); }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){ obj[key](); }, this);
```

ES2015 version:

```
var obj = {
    func1: () => console.log('func1'),
    func2: () => console.log('func2')
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key]());
```

**obj** must contain methods only